# How can I install 18.04 on S390X Z14? I think I need the 28/10/19 iso

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

zipl load onto hard disk fails during 18.04 install on s390x z14

I found that this problem was fixed in the Sept. 28, 2019 iso image.

Where can I download this iso image?

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about a daily ISO, they are dropped as later dailies are produced.

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/bionic/daily/20191031/bionic-server-s390x.iso

appears to be the most recent build (Oct-31).

That link will cease to work when later builds have been created and it gets dropped, so you can just navigate to from http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/ to whatever you want (release, architecture etc)

*Note:  Dailies do not always represent daily production (though this is the normal and purpose), at stages in the cycle they can be produced every fortnight, weekly, daily or more than once per day (esp. later in the cycle or if a daily had a serious problem)*

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The size looks right. I will try the install tomorrow. Hopefully the zipl failure has been fixed.

Comment: Ok I installed but hit the same error. Failed in "Install the ZIPL boot loader on a hard disk"

This installation is being done on a z14 native LPAR build with FCP SCSI disks. Two (256 GB) disks were used to create a logical volume and mounted as the root fs. 

Based on the following link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer/+bug/1680101, was closed in April of 2018. Any suggestions? I cannot create a boot partition on one of the two LUNs.

I was able to successfully install the system but not in a logical volume.

Comment: I would suggest raising a new bug report.  You need a developer on that team to see it, and that's the best way.  Even if convinced it's the same issue, I'd raise a new report as it'll be seen faster, and at worst will be marked duplicate (which would require the old one to be re-opened or looked at again to see why anyway..)  Raising a bug report on launchpad is your best bet.  (*17 people & me currently will see the bug raised just on IRC, not counting those who will receive email due to package etc* Bug reports get *dev* attention, and usually provide decent detail if `ubuntu-bug` is used)